# How to enable message encryption in Contiki / Cooja simulator?

Tags: encryption, simulation, emulation, contiki

I want to encrypt the messages that are exchanged between sensor nodes.

Can I do it without having access to real hardware sensor nodes, such as Tmote Sky?

Can software encryption/block ciphers only be simulated on Tmote Sky nodes? If I need to use hardware encryption algorithms, then should I have a real sensor node?

Also, I read that for symmetric encryption one must have real sensor nodes, but asymmetric encryption can work with emulated nodes as well?

Any documentation or description would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Contiki has LLSEC (link-layer security) layer. This layer is hardware independent, as it uses generic AES driver API instead of directly accessing the hardware. There are multiple AES drivers implemented in Contiki - a software-only version and a couple of hardware accelerated ones, including for CC2420 (the radio chip on Tmote Sky).

The problem with Cooja is that the HW acceleration feature of CC2420 is not implemented in the `mspsim` emulator. So HW acceleration is not going to work in Cooja as opposed to real Tmote Sky nodes; you must explicitly select the software-based AES driver in configuration:

```
#define AES_128_CONF aes_128_driver
```

The bottom line is that AES encryption will work in Cooja, but will be slow.

Now the example configuration of LLSEC - there is little LLSEC documentation around, but the basic setup is described in this [README file](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/core/net/llsec/noncoresec):

> Add these lines to your `project_conf.h` to enable `noncoresec`:
>
> ```
> #undef LLSEC802154_CONF_ENABLED
> #define LLSEC802154_CONF_ENABLED          1
> #undef NETSTACK_CONF_FRAMER
> #define NETSTACK_CONF_FRAMER              noncoresec_framer
> #undef NETSTACK_CONF_LLSEC
> #define NETSTACK_CONF_LLSEC               noncoresec_driver
> #undef NONCORESEC_CONF_SEC_LVL
> #define NONCORESEC_CONF_SEC_LVL           1
> ```
>
> NONCORESEC_CONF_SEC_LVL defines the length of MICs and whether
>   encryption is enabled or not.

The important paramter here is `NONCORESEC_CONF_SEC_LVL`, which corresponds to the IEEE 802.15.4 framer security levels, with numerical values from 0x0 to 0x07.

**To enable encryption, set it to 0x4:**

```
#define NONCORESEC_CONF_SEC_LVL 0x4
```

The other values are:

> - 0x00  No security  Data is not encrypted. Data authenticity is not validated.
> - 0x01  AES-CBC-MAC-32        MIC-32  Data is not encrypted. Data authenticity is validated.
> - 0x02    AES-CBC-MAC-64      MIC-64  Data is not encrypted. Data authenticity is validated.
> - 0x03    AES-CBC-MAC-128     MIC-128     Data is not encrypted. Data authenticity is validated.
> - 0x04    AES-CTR         ENC     Data is encrypted. Data authenticity is not validated.
> - 0x05    AES-CCM-32      AES-CCM-32  Data is encrypted. Data authenticity is validated.
> - 0x06    AES-CCM-64 AES-CCM-64   Data is encrypted. Data authenticity is validated.
> - 0x07    AES-CCM-128 AES-CCM-128 Data is encrypted. Data authenticity is validated.

To enable both encryption and authentication, set the level to 0x5, 0x6 or 0x7.

Another useful configuration parameter is `NONCORESEC_CONF_KEY`, the network-wide shared key.

As for the other questions, there is no support for hardware-accelerated *asymmetric* encryption on sensor nodes. Also, there are no software based implementations for that in mainline Contiki; there is no support (yet) for end-to-end security in general in this OS, as opposed to link-layer security. There *are* some projects that have developed DTLS and IPSEC for Contiki, but describing that goes beyond this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The llsec is the security stack. For example the anti-replay `llsec_driver` avoid replay attack.
About pure encryption (so no logic security), software encryption are available for all platform (not only skymote) with hardware boost (for some platform) ([contiki-os blog](http://contiki-os.blogspot.fr/) check at encryption paragraph).
Cooja is an emulator, not a simulator ([Cooja in depth](http://wireless.ictp.it/school_2015/presentations/firstweek/ICTP-Cooja-Presentation-version0.pdf)). So it simulates everything from the hardware. Therefore, you don't need a real mote to make test.
Symmetric and asymmetric encryption have differences on a logical point of view. But on hardware it's same : you'll send bits that represent a key. I don't see why it would be different for emulation.
For hardware encryption, if the mote support it, yes you can. If not you can't. (emulated or not).
Hope it helped.